# Can't install webapps in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, webapps

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I want to install Unity webapps like Twitter - Gmail and Facebook. I opened Gmail and Twitter in Firefox and Chromium in order to install them but nothing appears.

Do I have to install them or what should I do ?!!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Try `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-gmail` in order to see if this isn't a bug. After this open the Dash and search for `gmail`. Also edit your question to include the output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep unity\.webapps`. (You might also try seeing that Firefox is your default web browser and that in its Preferences, General tab, the option `Prompt integration options for any website` is checked.)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just too long to answer edwin's request;

I have the same problem, tried installing via terminal, only Thunderbird shows up when I search for gmail in dash. My output is;

> com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains @as []
>
> com.canonical.unity.webapps dontask-domains @as []
>
> com.canonical.unity.webapps index-update-time 43200
>
> com.canonical.unity.webapps integration-allowed true
>
> com.canonical.unity.webapps preauthorized-domains ['amazon.ca',
> 'amazon.cn', 'amazon.com', 'amazon.co.uk', 'amazon.de', 'amazon.es',
> 'amazon.fr', 'amazon.it', 'www.amazon.ca', 'www.amazon.cn',
> 'www.amazon.com', 'www.amazon.co.uk', 'www.amazon.de',
> 'www.amazon.es', 'www.amazon.fr', 'www.amazon.it', 'one.ubuntu.com']

When I visit a website I am prompted to install, I click to install and nothing happens. Reload the page and I am prompted again and so on.

Ubuntu 13.04, everything up to date using Chromium Version 28.0.1500.52 Ubuntu 13.04 (28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.13.04.3)